# How to implement REST API using NodeJs for group/multiple/batch insert in table of azure storage?

Tags: node.js, rest, azure-storage

I went through the documentation of REST BatchSave [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/performing-entity-group-transactions) but they didn't give any example or step for it as they give in insert/update/delete/fetch, i am not able to understand how to design REST API for batch save. I am done with insert, update, delete and fetch of entity from a table of azure datastore, but got stuck on Batch/Group/multiple insert in a table of azure datastore.
Need help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of implementation by Microsoft Azure storage Node.js Client library, please look into:

- [tablebatch.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/table/tablebatch.js)
- [batchresult.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/table/models/batchresult.js)
- [tableservice.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/table/tableservice.js) executeBatch function

Would you also share your concern about directly using azure-storage node.js package?

Best Wishes